# How move first item of arraylist to last position?

Tags: java, android

my code move to last arraylist:

```
 if (listItem.get(listItem.size() - 1).SortNo > 0) {
                    while (listItem.get(0).SortNo == 0) {

                        DTO_NightClinic dt = listItem.get(0);
                        listItem.remove(0);
                        listItem.add(dt);
                    }
                }
```

But common `listItem.remove(0);` it not working. and first item still exist at first position of arraylist.

Comment: your loop never fails

Comment: No, i had if (listItem.get(listItem.size() - 1).SortNo > 0) {

Comment: I told about while loop

Comment: if listItem.size() - 1).SortNo > 0 ,while loop will have to exit

Comment: If the condition is true, then how the while loop is terminated?

Comment: first items have SortNo =0 will move to last array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Collections.rotate(list, -1);
```

Just use rotate with `-1` place and it will do what you want

Input:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

Output:

```
2, 3, 4, 1
```

For more on [Collections#rotate(java.util.List,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate%28java.util.List,%20int%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.rotate(list, -1);
```

/...................................

Comment: Collections.swap: is it  swap or move?

Comment: sry its Collections.rotate

Comment: Update ur answer and some explaination to it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `Collections.rotate()` seems to feasible solution but it is some want extended task... see the source of `Collections.roatate()`

```
public static void rotate(List<?> lst, int dist) {
      ...............
        reverse(sublist1);
        reverse(sublist2);
        reverse(list);
}
```

it iterates through all Items of List and applies `Collections.reverse()` opearion thus consumes some time.

and here, as you are simply want to remove the first item from List and add it to the tail of List, You can do a simple trick like below sample...

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        arrayList.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println(arrayList.toString());
    // prints [1, 2, 3, 4]

    Integer removedItem = arrayList.remove(0);
    arrayList.add(removedItem); // adds to the end of the List
    System.out.println(arrayList.toString());
    // prints [2, 3, 4, 1]
```